# How to control which kivy version buildozer deploys on android?

Tags: android, version, kivy, buildozer

Which kivy version does buildozer deploy on android and is it possible to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, write a version in requirements, for example `requirements = kivy==1.9.1`.

Buildozer uses packages from `pip`, so if you write just `kivy`, it will download it into its virtualenv using command `pip install kivy` (that is `stable` branch).